# Parse.com Push Subscription does not work on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: parse-platform, windows-runtime, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to get Parse.com Push notifications running on Windows Phone 8.1 (from this [Tutorial](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/windows_phone/existing)).

It seems that the initialization works:

```
ParseClient.Initialize("my app-id", "my key");
```

But when I'm trying to subscribe to the broadcast channel, the following exception gets thrown:

```
await ParsePush.SubscribeAsync("");
```

**The notification platform is unable to connect to the cloud notification service. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E011B)**

It is an Universal App (C#) and I have enabled "Toast capable" within the Package.appxmanifest file.

I have also authenticated the Windows Store App by adding the Package Security Identifier and the Client Secret to the Parse.com Windows Push Credentials settings ([following this tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/windows-8-push-tutorial)).
But this does not solve the problem..

Any solutions regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Funny, it worked after I installed the beta-app from the market (and deleted it afterwards again).

The next deployment of the production-app via Visual Studio worked for me (no exception anymore) - The device is now connected to the Parse service :)